# Notification in laravel when new record is inserted using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I need to display notification when a new user added.

Here is my code in the view:

```
<script>
var old_count = 0;

setInterval(function(){    
  $.ajax({
    url : "/shownotify",
    success : function(data){
        if (data > old_count) {
            alert('new record on i_case');
            old_count = data;
        }
    }
  });
},1000);
```

In Route:

```
 Route::get('shownotify', ['uses' => 'DriverController@shownotify', 'as' => 'shownotify']);
```

In controller:

```
public function shownotify()
{
   return Move::count();
}
```

But I didn't get the results. Can anybody help?

Comment: what debugging have you done? Check your browser's console and network tools for errors and report anything you find here. Is the ajax call completing? What does it return, if anything? What HTTP code? Any errors on the server-side? You don't seem to have investigated this at all. "Didn't get the results" is what the user would say, but you're a programmer, so you need to give technical detail. The obvious thing is that `shownotify()` doesn't have a `return` statement in it, but if you'd done some debugging of the response you might have realised it yourself.

Comment: In the function `shownotify` you doesn't return anything

Comment: Error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)-shownotify
" And also jquery.min.js:4 GET http://localhost/shownotify() 404 (Not Found)

Comment: a 404 means that the server couldn't find anything to execute or return at the URL you have. So I guess your route is probably wrong. Once you fix that then you need to actually return some data from shownotify()

Comment: yes I got it I 've done a mistake,when i change something.Now I have replaced shownotify() to shownotify,it works!!!!!.But How do I display it in my admin panel topbar

Comment: Presumably you have some HTML which you need to populate with that content. We can't see that, so we have no idea what it's called, or if it's even possible. But you can look up the JavaScript syntax to insert content into an element in 100 places online.

Answer (score 1):

You're really not explaining what you're trying and what your problem is very well :/

But one thing that springs in my eye, is that you're not returning anything from the `shownotify()` method, so maybe just return the `$row` variable is what you need? :)

Comment: I just 've returned the $row variable but it shows the error "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
" in my console

Comment: Well, then your route is wrong or not defined or something. Have you tried hitting the `shownotify` in your browser? Is that working?

Comment: Then I guess it's your javascript that is trying to hit the wrong route :) Check the network tap in your chrome dev tools

Comment: Now it works(I 've did the small mistake added function bracket in url),But how do I dispaly in my admin panel topbar.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Create a new question on SO, where you explain your problem, what you have tried, that is happening and what you expected to happen :)

Comment: This has nothing to do with your original question, create a new one. And spend some time doing some testing and write a detailed post explaining your problem.